# How to get solid colors using QLinearGradient when styling QProgressBar?

Tags: c++, qt, qprogressbar

```
QProgressBar *b = new QProgressBar();

QString progressStyle = QString("::chunk {"
                                    "background-color: "
                                    "qlineargradient(x0: 0, x2: 1, "
                                    "stop: 0 green, stop: 0.6 green, "
                                    "stop: 0.6 orange, stop: 0.8 orange, "
                                    "stop: 0.8 transparent, stop: 1 transparent"
                                    ")}");

b->setStyleSheet(progressStyle);

b->setValue(80);
b->show();
```

I'm trying to use solid colors, each color separated from the other, but my code results in gradient colors.

Here's how it looks:

[image: Here is my work]

How can I avoid this gradient effect, and achieve the solid colors I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `0.0001`, to avoid color ranges from overlapping, which causes the gradient effect.

Solid colors:

```
"stop: 0 green, stop: 0.6 green, "
"stop: 0.60001 orange, stop: 0.8 orange, "
"stop: 0.80001 red, stop: 1 red"
```

Gradient:

```
"stop: 0 green, stop: 0.6 green, "
"stop: 0.6 orange, stop: 0.8 orange, "
"stop: 0.8 red, stop: 1 red"
```